# Trouble setting a default controller in MVC 2 RC Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

This should be simple, but alas...

I've set up an Admin area within my MVC 2 project (single project areas).  I've created a couple controllers and their respective view folders.  In the AreaRegistration.RegisterArea method, I've specified that I want the default controller to be "Dashboard":

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = "" }, new string[] { "Admin" }
        );
    }
```

If I navigate to url/Admin/Dashboard, the index comes up just fine.  What I want, though, is to allow the user to go to url/Admin/ and see the same thing.  When I do this, however, I get "The resource cannot be found".

I'm just getting my feet wet with MVC 2's Area implementation, and I don't think I'm doing anything overly complicated... Anyone had the same problem?  Do I need to specify a separate route, perhaps at the root, non-area level?

Comment: BTW, that string array param at the end of the MapRoute call is extraneous, I tried adding it in an ignorant attempt at fixing the problem, but since there isn't a controller name conflict in the rest of the project, I think it's useless in this case.

Comment: Not yet.  I had to set the proj aside for a couple days for other priorities.  I'll dig again this evening though.  For the interim I just linked directly to the Area/Controller/Action route I intended the default to be.

Comment: @SocialAddict, check out the solution I provided below.  Is your situation similar or were you just curious?

Comment: this works but then causes errors with the shared views as its looking in the root not the area, cant find a tidy way of fixing this, any ideas?

Comment: Still happens with MVC4... I have an area called v1 so I doubt the name "admin" has any conflicts whatsoever as you speculate in your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, odd.  So I added a different area, aptly named "Administration", set the default controller and added the appropriate controller, view, etc. and it worked.  The difference?  In my first case, I was using "Admin" as the area.

Comment: This warrants further research as I'd like to know why "Admin" was causing trouble.  Is there a buried naming conflict somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this additional route:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default2",
            "Admin"
            new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = "" }
        )
```

Comment: yeah, I had tried that, no go.  I tried putting it in both the AreaRegistration class as well as the global, prior to the default route.

Comment: Hmm, I can't get it to work in my project either. I will work on it some more later. In the meantime, you will need Phil Haack's route diagnostic tool available here: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/17/testing-routes-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
context.MapRoute(
               "Admin_default3",
               "Admin/{action}",
               new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" }
               );
```